# How to declare dynamic arrays in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I am trying to declare a dynamic array in SystemVerilog source, but getting an error like:

> Dynamic range only allowed in SystemVerilog.

The tool I am using is ModelSim. The piece of code is like this:

```
module sv1;

  reg [7:0] memory []; // 8 bit memory with 16 entries

endmodule
```

What are probable problems?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code. The only issue is that the simulator you are using does not support SystemVerilog.

You can try your SystemVerilog code at http://edaplayground.com

Comment: Even I tried this with vivado 14.2 I am getting same error. Is there any library declaration needed for this to work??

Comment: Tools which support SystemVerilog normally require the `.sv` file extension or require you to pass an argument such as `-sv` to indicate that the source is SV and not Verilog.

Answer (score 1):

Most tools treat source files on the command line or project list as Verilog unless you give the file a `*.sv` extension to have them recognized as SystemVerilog. The reason is there are still a number of tools that do not support SystemVerilog and you have to explicitly ask for it.

There is also a ModelSim `-sv` switch which treats all files as SystemVerilog, but you can run into compilation problems if your legacy Verilog code uses SystemVerilog reserved keywords like `bit`.

Comment: indeed I have used extension as .sv , I am getting this error which says Vivado Synthesis ignores library specification for Verilog or SystemVerilog files. [C:/Users/Prasad/Desktop/vivado/system/proj1/proj1.srcs/sources_1/new/main.sv]

Comment: I am having xil_defaultlib (1) in liabrary section. Is any other liabrary is needed to include??

Comment: That is a completely different question.